# Is it possible to match any wide character that appears more than once using only regxp?

Tags: regex

For example, in this string with no `\s`:

```
abodnpjdcqe
```

only `d` should be matched.
But in my case there are thousands of different characters, is it possible to use ONLY regxp to match all characters that appear in the string more than once? It seems that all other problems use other tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to find characters that are present two times in a string as anubhava demonstrates it, and I don't see any other regex pattern to do it.

However, there are problems with an only regex way:

1. The complexity of this kind of pattern is very high, and you will experience problems (with backtracking limits and execution time) if your string is long and if there are few duplicates.
2. This way is unable to see if a duplicate character have been already found. For example the string `a123a456a789a`, the pattern will return `a` three times instead of one. If your goal is to obtain a list of unique duplicate characters, it can be problematic *(but easy to solve programmatically)*

So, to answer your question: my answer is no.

a simple way, to do it with code is to loop over the characters of your string and to build an associative array where the keys are the characters and the values the number of occurences. Then, removes each item that has the value 1 and extract the keys.

Note: you can solve the problem of duplicate results *(2.)* using this pattern:

```
(.)(?=(?:(?!\1).)*\1(?:(?!\1).)*$)
```

or if possessive quantifiers are available:

```
(.)(?=(?:(?!\1).)*+\1(?:(?!\1).)*+$)
```

but I'm afraid that the complexity may be even more high.

So, using your favorite language stay from far the best way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
([a-zA-Z])(?=.*\1)
```

#### Explanation:

- Regex uses `([a-zA-Z])` to match any letter and captures it as `group #1` i.e. `\1`
- A positive lookahead `(?=.*\1)` then makes sure this match is successful **only** when it is followed by at least one of the backreference `\1` i.e. the character itself.

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mU4sZ5/1)

Comment: By adding all wide characters into `[]` this seems to work. But as @casimir-et-hippolyte said, the complexity is very high. So I have written a problem with `unordered_map` to solve it. Thank you all the same.